# UPDATE JOIN -> INSERT ON NULL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update, left-join

This question is very simple but I found no answer, yet, by searching for "UPDATE JOIN INSERT" and other stuff like that.

I need an UPDATE for two tables ('main' and 'sub') while one dataset might not exist. then there should be a simple INSERT executed before... In one statement.

'main' always exist.
'sub' does not.

My dreamy-SQL-solution is this one:

```
UPDATE main LEFT JOIN sub on main.primary=sub.primary
SET main.foo='bar', sub.foo2='bar2'
CASE sub.primary IS NULL {INSERT INTO sub SET sub.primary=main.primary};
```

The 'CASE'-part is freestyle and presumably won't work.
But what is the correct way of doing it?

<s>It absolutely has to be an "UPDATE [...] LEFT JOIN [...] SET a=aVal, b=bVal, [...]"- Statement.</s>
It has to be extendable for up to 5 LEFT JOIN tables and work without "SET(..) VALUES(..)"

Is there any possible solution?

Comment: Reverse the logic, and google for that instead

Comment: INSERT INTO table ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE ...

Comment: Is there a reason `It absolutely has to be an "UPDATE [...] LEFT JOIN [...] SET a=aVal, b=bVal, [...]"- Statement.`?

Comment: Why does it absolutely have to be an UPDATE statement? Is this a real life solution or an assignment or an intellectual challenge? ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE is the simplest way to do it. Why complicate it?

Comment: @mseifert My thoughts exactly. Though written as an insert, it would achieve an identical end goal.

Comment: The reason is the logic I am using already in PHP-code. As far as I know, it is not possible to use "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" with SET a=aVal, b=bVal. Only SET -> VALUES and that does not harmonize with the functions Input. Since fieldName and fieldValue are not seperated just by "=".

Comment: @Charliexyx you can do many sets in 1 DUPE KEY UPDATE, please see answer below for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An UPDATE statement can modify rows that exist. In can't add new rows. Absolutely.

An INSERT statement can be used to add rows to a table. It's definitely possible to write a statement that adds the "missing" rows.

But if "it absolutely has to be an UPDATE" statement to add rows, then there is no solution.

Comment: I thought about an INSERT and an UPDATE Statement executed in one Statement. It is possible to use Subselects in statements. Is that not still one Statement?

Comment: It's possible to run an INSERT statement in the context of a trigger on an UPDATE; we can define an trigger that  adds rows to an audit table whenever a row is updated, for example. (Note that it's still an INSERT statement that's inserting the rows, even though that's triggered from the execution of an UPDATE statement.) But I don't believe it's possible to insert rows to the same table that's referenced in an UPDATE statement; I think that's a restriction. And even if that were possible, it would still be an INSERT statement adding the rows, not the UPDATE statement.

Comment: Sounds like a great solution, if it works on the same table. Sadly triggers are not allowed, because it makes everything too complex. (No MySQL Logic. Any logic has to be visible in the statement for easier maintenance)

Answer (score 6):

`ON DUPLICATE KEY` is probably your best bet.
Something around the lines of:

```
INSERT INTO sub s (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT m.col1, m.col2, m.col3
FROM MAIN m
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE SET m.foo='bar', s.foo2='bar2'
```

If you need to left join as part of your query, simply add it in the select like so:

```
INSERT INTO sub s (col1, col2, col3)
SELECT m.col1, m.col2, m.col3
FROM MAIN m
LEFT JOIN sub s ON s.primary = m.primary
LEFT JOIN sub2 s2 ON s2.primary = m.primary
ON DUPLICATE KEY
UPDATE SET m.foo='bar', s.foo2='bar2', s.foobar = s2.foobar
```

Comment: OP said that 'it absolutely has to be an "UPDATE ... LEFT JOIN ... '  statement. And this is clearly *not* an UPDATE statement. This is an example of an INSERT statement.

Comment: @spencer7593 Even though they stated they wanted the final answer to be an update, I figured it was worth putting this answer out there, as it is the best solution to the problem the OP is facing currently.

Comment: Will this solution still work if it is not just one LEFT JOIN but 5 LEFT JOINS?

Comment: @Charliexyx try it yourself & use google, but I assure you it will when coded properly . . .

Comment: @Charliexyx it will. If you have issues, you can also create a temp table as part of your select. I'll work on/include a temp table for you right now.

Comment: On second thought, no temp table required.

Comment: @Pachonk Thanks a lot for your help, so far, but it looks like an unsolvable problem for me. Where ist my mistake? INSERT INTO (SELECT main.foo, sub.bar FROM main LEFT JOIN sub ON main.primary=sub.primary)
SET sub.bar='foobar', main.foo='barfoo'
WHERE main.primary=1
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
SET sub.foobar='foobar', main.barfoo='barfoo'

Comment: Well, I think this gets too complicated. I just check now if I have to Insert those lines for all of those LEFT JOIN tables before in a preceding function.

Comment: The reason it doesn't work is because the syntax for an insert is wrong. If you follow my above, it should work nicely.